# Get ID attribute from Kendo dropdownList change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using the kendo dropdownlisthelper, which has a change event, see below

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .Name(Model.Name)
        .Text(Model.PlaceHolder)
        .BindTo(Model.ListItems)
        .DataTextField("Text")
        .DataValueField("Value")
        .Enable(Model.Enabled)
        .Events(e =>
        {
            e.Change("change");
        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new {@id= Model.ID.ToString() })
```

The function that handles the change event:

```
function change(e) {
    var dataItem = this.dataItem(e.item);
    console.log("selected values (" + dataItem.Text + " : " + dataItem.Value + ")");
}
```

SO this displays the selected value in the console.

The Question:
I'm struggling to work this out, but how do i display the Name and ID of the parent element that made the call to the change event(in this case the drop-down list).

So basically i want to display these values:
- Name attribute of the dropdown list
- Id attribute of the dropdown list

Cheers!

Comment: What do you mean - "how do i display the Name and ID of the parent element that made the call " ?  Please provide more details on what you whant to achive

Comment: Your answer below was useful and was the answer i was looking for. It would be interesting to know if there was a way to pass the entire model to the change event..hmm.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this approach to get **Id** of element on which event have occured

```
function change(e) {
    var elementId = e.sender.element[0].id
}
```

Comment: That's useful. This means that you can get the entire element through this code: var inputElement = e.sender.element.context;  This variable will then give you access to all the attributes on your input element. Thanks Anton

Comment: Working Fine :)